# Obtener imagen de objeto HTML con JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, imagen

Estoy realizando una función donde al hacer click se despliegue todo el contenido de una tarjeta que contiene el resumen de un artículo. El problema que me encuentro es que se muestra todo correctamente pero no sé como mostrar la imagen, he utilizado con la propiedad `.html()` y me recoge el contenido de la etiqueta y con la propiedad `.attr("src")` solo me obtiene la ruta donde se almacena la imagen.

Tengo el siguiente código HTML:

```
<div class="articulo">
                        <div class="artModoMovil">
                            <div class="inverter">
                                <h3>Título de articulo<small> Datos de publicación</small></h3>
                                <p>Temática</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inverterImg">
                                <img class="imagenArt" src="img/prueba.png" alt="Esto es una imagen de prueba">
                            </div>
                            <div class="texto">
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto

                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es textoEsto es textoEsto es textoEsto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                                Esto es textoEsto es textoEsto es texto
                                Esto es texto
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">Leer más</a> <br>
                        <small>Aquí va el autor</small>
                    </div>
```

Y el siguiente código JS:

```
function abrirArticulo(){
  $(".articulo").click(function(){
      var titulo = $(".articulo .inverter h3").html();
      var tema = $(".articulo .inverter p").html();
      var imagen = $(".articulo img").attr("src");
      var contenido = $(".texto").html();

      var nuevoCont = "";
      nuevoCont += "<h1>" + titulo + "</h1>" + 
              "<h3>" + tema + "</h3>" + 
              "<div>" + imagen + "</div>" +
              "<div>" + contenido + "</div>";

      $(".cuerpo").html(nuevoCont);
      $(".cuerpo").css({
          "background-color" : "white",
          "margin-top" : "3%",
          "padding" : "2%",
          "border-radius" : "1em"
      });
  });  
};
```

El resultado obtenido es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Dónde está la imagen (origen) y dónde quieres mostrarla (destino)?

Comment: La imagen está en la siguiente ruta img/prueba.png y la quiero mostrar en la posición que aparece en la imagen adjuntada

Comment: En la variable `nuevoCont` almaceno la información que quiero mostrar, por lo que la imagen se muestra de un `div`común y corriente. El problema no radica en el origen y el destino, si no en la manera de cargar la imagen, es decir, lo que quiero es obtener la imagen y almacenarla en una variable. Me disculpo si mi manera de formular la pregunta no fue la correcta

Comment: Para que la imagen se muestre en `nuevoCont` solo tendrías que agregarla como un elemento `img` indicando el `src`. Sería cuestión de modificar tu variable `imagen`, creando en ella un elemento válido, porque ahí obtienes solamente la URL de la imagen sin más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que en `nuevoCont` estás mostrando solamente la URL de la imagen. Tienes que crear un elemento `img` con su respectivo `src`, que sería el dato que recogiste en la variable `imagen`.

Esa parte de `nuevoCont` quedaría así más o menos: `'<div> <img src=" '+ imagen + '" alt="Imagen en el otro div"/></div>'` ...

Por ejemplo:

```js
$(".articulo").click(function() {
    var titulo = $(".articulo .inverter h3").html();
    var tema = $(".articulo .inverter p").html();
    var imagen = $(".articulo img").attr("src");
    var contenido = $(".texto").html();

    var nuevoCont = "";
    nuevoCont += "<h1>" + titulo + "</h1>" +
      "<h3>" + tema + "</h3>" +
      '<div> <img src=" '+ imagen + '" alt="Imagen en el otro div"/></div>' +
      "<div>" + contenido + "</div>";

    $(".cuerpo").html(nuevoCont);
    $(".cuerpo").css({
      "background-color": "white",
      "margin-top": "3%",
      "padding": "2%",
      "border-radius": "1em"
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="articulo">
  <div class="artModoMovil">
    <div class="inverter">
      <h3>Título de articulo<small> Datos de publicación</small></h3>
      <p>Temática</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inverterImg">
      <img class="imagenArt" src="img/prueba.png" alt="Esto es una imagen de prueba">
    </div>
    <div class="texto">
      Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto
      Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es texto Esto es textoEsto es textoEsto es textoEsto es texto Esto es texto Esto es textoEsto es textoEsto es texto Esto es texto
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">Leer más</a> <br>
  <small>Aquí va el autor</small>
</div>
<div class="cuerpo"></div>
```